# Modal popup File Upload

Tags: jquery, ajax, file-upload, uploadify, simplemodal

I use Eric martin's contact form modal popup in one of my personal projects. I wish to add file upload to it, however when I try to get the file, I'm able to view the file. I'm pretty much new with Jquery. I tried couple of AJAX Upload and uploadify, thats also didnt work. Please suggest me some solution to proceed. My Frontend is php and backend is mysql.

Answer (score 1):

I've done something similar in a project and it is quite a bit of code to deal with an Ajax Upload. I suggest you get it working first w/o SimpleModal, then try and integrate it.